# How to connect to a computer on LAN using some other account then earlier used?

Tags: authentication, lan, automation

I have 7 computers on the LAN in a small home office, and one of the computers PC01 has data that will be accessed by other users. Till now, all I had to do was share the relevant folders with "Everyone" and they would be able to access it.

Now (some critical data got deleted) however, I want to set up a Userid that has only read access, and let everyone use that so that no one deletes anything by mistake. However, since everyone had saved the authentication info when they first accessed the computer, no one is getting the prompt for entering the password.  How to make sure that people have to enter usernames passwords every time they try to access a file on the main computer?

PS - I don't know how to set up domains, and don't want to if it is complicated. I have set the permissions on the folders so that everyone can log in with ID - User1 if they want to view files. Two ppl will be able to login as User2 with full edit permissions. 
I have password protected some files, and that should work, unless someone deletes the files themselves :) , hence the need to set up permissions like this.
PPS - I guess I can use ccleaner to cleanup all stored passwords - but is that really the right solution? Running Win7 Professional on the main PC - all others are WinXP or Win7 Home Basic.

Answer (score 0):

the solution seems fairly simple from my point of view - either you can:

1) do the [following procedure](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-delete-saved-passwords-for-network-drives-in-windows/) on each of the user's PCs (that would be quite tedious)

2) Remove all the users who can access the shared folder, remove the share, recreate it and create two brand new user accounts with strong passwords that can access the folder, with their corresponding permissions.

3) If these don't work, remove the share completely, and then recreate it while give it another, slightly different name (and give the other people using it a batch-based script that would reflect the changes in their systems). Then again create the users who can access this share.

domain would really help you with setting AD folder permissions, but that would require a Windows Server distribution with DNS and AD installed.

Comment: Thanks!!! I managed to get it to work as per your suggestions...

Comment: Very glad to be of help. Happy networking!